# Loop over lines in file and subtract previous line from current line

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a file that contains some numbers

```
$ cat file.dat
0.092593
0.048631
0.027957
0.030699
0.026250
0.038156
0.011823
0.013284
0.024529
0.022498
0.013217
0.007105
0.018916
0.014079
```

I want to make a new file that contains the difference of the current line with the previous line. Expected output should be

```
$ cat newfile.dat
-0.043962
-0.020674
0.002742
-0.004449
0.011906
-0.026333
0.001461
0.011245
-0.002031
-0.009281
-0.006112
0.011811
-0.004837
```

Thinking this was trivial, I started with this piece of code

```
f="myfile.dat"    
while read line; do
    curr=$line
    prev=

    bc <<< "$line - $prev" >> newfile.dat
done < $f
```

but I realized quickly that I have no idea how to access the previous line in the file. I guess I also need to account for that no subtraction should take place when reading the first line. Any guidance on how to proceed is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 { print $0 - prev } { prev = $0 }' <file.dat
-0.043962
-0.020674
0.002742
-0.004449
0.011906
-0.026333
0.001461
0.011245
-0.002031
-0.009281
-0.006112
0.011811
-0.004837
```

Doing this in a shell loop calling `bc` is cumbersome.  The above uses a simple `awk` script that reads the values off of the file one by one and for any line past the first one, it prints the difference as you describe.

The first block, `NR > 1 { print $0 - prev }`, conditionally prints the difference between this and the previous line if we've reached line two or further (`NR` is the number of records read so far, and a "record" is by default a line).

The second block, `{ prev = $0 }`, unconditionally sets `prev` to the value on the current line.

Redirect the output to `newfile.dat` to save the result there:

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 { print $0 - prev } { prev = $0 }' <file.dat >newfile.dat
```

Related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

---

There was some mentioning of the slowness of calling `bc` in a loop.  The following is a way of using a single invocation of `bc` to do the arithmetics while still reading the data in a shell loop (I would not actually recommend solving this problem in this way, and I'm only showing it here for people interested in co-processes in `bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc bc

{
    read prev

    while read number; do
        printf '%f - %f\n' "$number" "$prev" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
        prev=$number

        read -u "${COPROC[0]}" result
        printf '%f\n' "$result"
    done
} <file.dat >newfile.dat

kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

The value in `${COPROC[1]}` is the standard input file descriptor of `bc` while `${COPROC[0]}` is the standard output file descriptor of `bc`.

Comment: If prev is the value on the current line, how does this actually work? Because if I substitute prev = $0 into the first block, we get {print $0 - $0}.

Comment: @Yoda `prev` is the value on the previous line.  For the first line, the first block is not executed (due to the `NR > 1` condition), so `prev` only gets the value of the first line (and nothing else happens).  For the second line, the difference between the second and first line is printed before `prev` is set to the value of the second line.  The blocks are executed in order, and for each line.

Comment: @Yoda So `prev` is the value on the current line only at the very end of processing that line, before continuing with the next line.  When we actually _use_ `prev`, it is the value of the previous line.

Answer (score 4):

Using some straightforward GNU utilities, and no shell loops:

```bash
paste -d- <(head -n-1 file.dat) <(tail -n+2 file.dat) | bc
```

The idea here is to duplicate the input file into two columns; offset the second column by 1 line, and paste the columns together with `-` as a separator.  `head` and `tail` are used to trim off the last line of the 1st column and first line of 2nd column respectively, to achieve the necessary offsetting.  The resulting list is the required list of arithmetic differences that is piped to `bc` for evaluation.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TY7LCsJADEX3fkWWikxJMs9Acadbv2H6kBaKCO3Sfx9npiLuDif3htvFdUp93OACj3kZmyFj28L1fjtgg8JWdAETnKYC7MX6AhqdSDWOLVYTyLoCRIFrizQHUzPG8h5mI@F7ovoHPaGtJgjtdYNeDnlBesV1G0ENCtrjNMYB1FPRb@cp2y3OS7Zn/rNv6PqUPg).

---

Alternatively, if you like `sed`, you can do this:

```bash
sed '1{s/$/-\\/;p;d};${p;d};s/.*/&\n&-\\/' file.dat | bc
```

This duplicates each line and inserts `-\` at the end of the second version of each line.  The first and last lines are treated differently to generate the necessary expressions.  The sed output ends up something like this:

```bash
a-\
b
b-\
c
c-\
d
```

These again are valid arithmetic differences that `bc` can evaluate.  Not that `bc` understands the line-continuation backslashes at the ends of every other line.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RY7LCsIwEEX3/YosSguCSSbvocWdbv2BbvoSBREh7qrfHpup4GoO9zHcoY/XNPYvdmCX233m04pty47nUyG5RGVRZzDBacigPFqfQUuHSIpTVpISwLoMAEFRC7QKhjLGqi2sDIafBfRHepCWlICw1Y30WKwLUpwnVsMSRSn2XSeaZzN9mnKhEwXfiap7VNmp/@PfbBhT@gI).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to try and force the shell script into working, you were just missing some initialization:

```
f=myfile.dat
prev=0
while read line; do
    bc <<< "$line - $prev"
    prev=$line
done < $f > newfile.dat
```

... where I also moved the redirection outside of the loop, just to save some I/O.

The `bc` solution does not print leading zeroes, while [the awk solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470033/117549) does.

Comment: Certainly shell loops are generally slow, but even slower is spawning a `bc` process for every iteration of the loop.  You can simply echo the `"$line - $prev"` expression into a pipe which is evaluated by `bc` outside of the loop: https://tio.run/##TZBNDoIwEIX3PcWEsJX0l7YR3OnWMwAtgQTBoJGYeHdsB4129eZ7byYzratbtzbVHQ5webb94DMXiqKA4/lEaEYtV1ZEIU0uWBRcW6WjEDS3FknOFUVimMqjYMxw7GKCG4kZqfgW5tKaj8VwDtWMKiTGsq1dUm1J2GBty99W5Dr7R0nJ0gUAs68cDP3o9@AmAuH5ppsgSSODHaQxnaCBfciJm4JZQNrCC@omHD365Tsfv@G/fgM

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `exec` redirection to read successive lines of the input file from multiple points in the script - once before the loop (to set up the initial value), then repeatedly during it (for each new value to subtract):

```
exec 3<file.dat
read prev<&3
while read curr ; do
        bc <<< "$curr - $prev" >> newfile.dat
        prev=$curr
done <&3
```

Comment: Using `{ read prev; while ...; do ...; done; } <file.dat`, you avoid having to juggle file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

I use arrays. I use them for everything. I cannot remember how awk and sed work without extensive study of the man pages. Here is the way I would do it.

```
f=( $(< file.dat) )
for ((num=1;num<=${#f[@]};num++))
do
    echo $(bc <<< ${f[$num]}-${f[(($num-1))]})>>differences.dat
done
```

This is the way I understand it. It has the objectionable features of some of the other answers: looping and calling bc over and over. However, it only reads the file once, like the answers using sed and awk.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
num <- as.data.frame(num)
num$sub_num <- num[c(2:14, c("0")), ]
num$diff <- num$num - num$sub_num
```

Comment: This is not just poorly formatted, it doesn't even specify what programming language is used.